# How do I loop and read PHP variables from other pages in my basic PHP website?

Tags: php, loops, variables, global-variables

I have a small, simple website with a portfolio. There are five projects in the portfolio, each in its own folder. Each `/portfolio/project/index.php` page has a set of variables at the top, kind of like YAML front matter, but it's just a set of PHP variables.

I want to put a loop on the `/portfolio/index.php` page of the portfolio that looks into each project folder, reads the index file, and automatically creates a link to each portfolio folder (not file, just folder as in "`/portfolio/project-x/`") with the page's `$pageLink` and `$pageTitle` placed inside the anchor tag.

The idea being if I add another project, I can just drop a new project folder into the portfolio folder, and it will show up as a link on the portfolio page thanks to the loop.

I'm just learning PHP, and I can't figure it out. I've read about scope, but I'm still missing something. I'm trying to keep this very simple.

```
/portfolio/project-1/index.php      
/portfolio/project-2/index.php      
/portfolio/project-3/index.php      
/portfolio/project-4/index.php      
/portfolio/project-5/index.php
```

Each `/project-x/index.php` page has a set of variables like so:

```
<?php
$pageTitle = "Project X";
$pageLink = "/portfolio/project-x/";
?>
```

On the `/portfolio/index.php` page I have tried a bunch of things, but I'm not getting it.

Here's my general concept:

```
<?php
foreach(glob("/portfolio/*/index.php") as $project){
echo "<a href=\"" . $project->$pageLink . "\">" . $project->$pageTitle . "</a>" . "<br>";
}
?>
```

I managed to get it kinda working once, but the loop took the title from the portfolio page and repeated it. Then I messed it up and couldn't get back to that. There's probably something I should read up on, but I don't know what to search for.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `include` the file before you can make use of the variables inside them. Note, the performance of your index page will degrade the more and more projects you add, but the impact will probably be negligible.

```
<?php

foreach (glob('portfolio/*/index.php') as $file) {
    ob_start();
    include $file;
    ob_end_clean();
    echo '<a href="'.$pageLink.'">'.$pageTitle.'</a><br>' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

After the loop, `$pageLink` and `$pageTitle` will still hold the values of the last file to be included.

Comment: Thanks. That's not working, because it includes all of the content from the project pages, and displays the title tag from the portfolio page. I just want to get the variables from the projects and not display all of their contents.

Comment: @Dcodes There is a way to ignore the output, check edited answer, you need `ob_start` and `ob_end_clean` around the include.

Comment: Nothing shows at all when I try the edited code. Thanks though.

Comment: Hmm that's strange, my test script is working just fine...

Comment: @Dcodes I would suggest trying a different approach, you could have a metadata.json file in each project directory that both the project index and the full index could read from instead.